# Free tools to generate HTML from a picture

Tags: gratis, artificial-intelligence, code-generation, llm

What are free tools to generate HTML from a picture of a website?

Just to quickly implement designers' work into code.

I want to upload a picture and get HTML, CSS from the service.

Comment: Welcome Self Smarted! Can you please clarify what you are asking?  Thanks!

Comment: As in recreate the site from nothing more than an image of it? This will not be possible, there are simply too many things underlying that cannot be seen, therefore no frame of reverence for any code to assume what is under the hood. The closest you *MAY* get is mirroring with something like wget, but since so much content is dynamically created and or drawn these days, it would be a partial at best.

Comment: Are you looking for recommendations for software that takes a static image (screenshot) of a website and generates HTML and CSS to render a page that looks the same?  Of course, the new HTML page wouldn't actually do anything except display static content.  Is this what you are wanting?

Comment: @RockPaperLz-MaskitorCasket yes, exactly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are some AI attempts at this like this [Screeshot to code](https://github.com/emilwallner/Screenshot-to-code) AI model that you can run with Python locally. After testing it I can't really say its 97% accuracy from description is, ironically, accurate. It depends on how complex the website is and how heavily it's based on images, I'd guess.

Anything more stable and free it's not quite findable I'd say, at this moment.